# cronJob and HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, express, cron, httprequest

i'm new to web development and have some questions about http requests and cron jobs. I npm installed cron and wanted to incorporate it into my app, where app.js is getting requests from clients that adds data into a database (using mongoose) from a form that client filled out. I want to run  a script (executer.js) to be called every 10 seconds to execute a task that will use the data in the same database. Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't use setInterval(job_callback, 10000) ?

Comment: You could use also a OS cron job that execute some .js

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a cron job for this (though if you need such a library there is the excellent: https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron). I'd recommend using setInterval for your particular example.

See https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args for detailed documentation on this.

```
var intervalMs = 10000;
function updateDB() {
   console.log("Updating db..");
   /* insert db update code here. */
}

setInterval(updateDB, intervalMs);
```

Comment: If the server is executing updateDB() every 10s, can it still receive http requests or will it block?

Comment: It can still process requests, it won't block them!

Comment: Thanks! One last thing, if I'm writing updateDB() function in another javascript file, how do I import it into app.js (the main file) to use it and can I access the database data from that file?

Comment: You can create a separate module to do this, and then you can reference in app.js! See https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp for an example.